# Symfony2 1:M / 1:1 Relationship and Sonata Admin Form

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-sonata, sonata-admin

I've hitting my head against the wall for countless hours now and I hope SO can be of help!

I have Retailer, Branch and RetailerBranches entities which work just fine, retailers can have many branches and a branch can only have one retailer. The hard part happens when trying to make Sonata Admin (SonataAdminBundle) play nice with that relationship. In their simplest form, they look like this:

**Retailer entity**

```
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="ID", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * Relation
     * 
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="RetailerBranches", mappedBy="Retailer", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    protected $branches;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->branches = new ArrayCollection();
    }
```

**RetailerBranches join table**

```
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="ID", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="Retailer_ID", referencedColumnName="ID", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Retailer", inversedBy="branches")
     */
    private $retailer;

    /**
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="Branch_ID", referencedColumnName="ID", nullable=false, unique=true)
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Branch", inversedBy="retailer")
     */
    private $branch;
```

**Branch entity**

```
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="ID", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * Relation
     * 
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="RetailerBranches", mappedBy="branch", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $retailer;
```

The harder part happens when trying generate the form to allow that relationship to take shape:

**RetailerAdmin**

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        $formMapper
            ->with('Branches')
                ->add('branches', 'sonata_type_collection', array(
                    'required' => false,
                    'by_reference' => false
                ), array(
                    'edit' => 'inline',
                    'inline' => 'table',
                ))
                ->end()
        ;
    }
```

**RetailerBranchesAdmin**

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        if ($this->hasRequest()) {
            $link_parameters = array('context' => $this->getRequest()->get('context'));
        } else {
            $link_parameters = array();
        }

        $formMapper
            ->add('succursale', 'sonata_type_model_list', array(
                'class' => 'VeloRetailerBundle:Branch',
                'required' => false,
            ), array(
                'edit' => 'inline',
                'inline' => 'table',
            ))
        ;
    }
```

***The problem:***

All this sort of works, here's a screenshot:
[image]

There's a Retailer and its Branches. Yay.

Problem 1: The "Add new" button at the bottom attempts to add a RetailerBranches object instead of a simple Branch object which obviously doesn't work.

Problem 2: This method also doesn't allow the user to modify a Branch inline.

I feel like I'm close to the solution, but I just cannot quite get there. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This Sonata again... I see so many people fighting it longer than it'd take to write all that stuff yourself. Why do you need it at all? If you need stuff like Sonata, you probably want a CMS, not a framework.

Comment: That's what I'm about to do. It's a neat piece of code, but the documentation is so, so poor.

Comment: I have found another way to get this done, will work on it tomorrow and post my findings.

Comment: I'm using Sonata Admin for half a year now and run into many not documented use cases. But it is in open source project and a lot of people are doing an awesome job on improving and adding new features. That's why I took the uses cases, talked to the contributors about there best practice and added them to docs. It's a simple GitHub fork and adding some lines. Feel free to join @Pier-Luc Gendreau and Elnur Abdurrakhimov. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For those running into the same problem, I posted the solution on [GitHub](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/issues/1254)

.

Comment: It would be very nice to have the contents here with some explanation instead of a just a link :)

Answer (score 1):

When needing to edit OneToOne or other relationships on the same page in Sonata Admin you could also create Admin classes for each Entity (and add to config.yml) and simply add the entire entity to your form in you main Admin class like so:

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    $formMapper
    ->add('yourLinkedProperty', 'sonata_type_admin')
    //other form fields
    ->end()
```

see Sonata Doc http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/form_types.html