# Saving embedded collections

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, sonata-admin

I have 2 Entities:

```
Game
Batting
```

A Game has several other properties, `date`, `location` etc
A Game has several `Batting` Entites, i.e a game of cricket
A Batting has several properties, `Runs, Dismissal, Player`

`Game.php`

```
 /**
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Batting", mappedBy="game", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 */
 private $battings;

/**
 * Add battings
 *
 * @param \CW\CricketBundle\Entity\Batting $battings
 * @return Game
 */

public function addBatting(\CW\CricketBundle\Entity\Batting $battings)
{
    $this->battings[] = $battings;

    return $this;
}
```

`Batting.php`

```
 /**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="CW\CricketBundle\Entity\Game", inversedBy="battings", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="game_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
 private $game;
```

`GameAdmin.php`

```
->with("Batting")
  ->add('battings', 'sonata_type_collection', array(), array(
      'edit' => 'inline',
      'inline' => 'table',
      'sortable' => 'id',
  ))
```

You can see what this like like below

[image: Screenshot of above in SonataAdmin]

The prblem is when adding a `Batting` and saving the `Game`.

I'd expect the `game_id` to be saved in the batting db table, but its always NULL.

Any ideas what is wrong with my code?

Thanks

EDIT:

Changed code to:

```
public function addBatting(\CW\CricketBundle\Entity\Batting $battings)
{
    $battings->setGame($this);

    $this->battings[] = $battings;

    return $this;
}
```

and

```
public function setGame(\CW\CricketBundle\Entity\Game $game)
{
    $this->game = $game;

    return $this;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps my question (and answer) can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15629225/symfony2-1m-11-relationship-and-sonata-admin-form/15974241#15974241

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the game on each of your batting object.

```
public function addBatting(\CW\CricketBundle\Entity\Batting $battings)
{
    $battings->setGame($this);

    $this->battings[] = $battings;

    return $this;
}
```

Comment: That hasn't changed anything, the `game_id` is still NULL

Comment: I've updated my question with the code you provided and included my `setGame` method too

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so chnging my admin form class to the following:

```
        ->add('battings', 'sonata_type_collection',
            array(
                'by_reference' => false
            ),
            array(
                'edit' => 'inline',
                'inline' => 'table',
                'allow_delete' => true
            )
        )
```

Seemed to work. Now when I save, the `game_id` is set.